# Error writing to Dropbox from Java

Tags: java, image, file, dropbox

I've made a java program for bulk manipulation of images. I have a problem where if I try to output files it works fine unless the output directory is managed by Dropbox at which point it fails almost every time.

I occasionally have a similar issue saving from Photoshop to Dropbox, the difference is that even when Photoshop says it's failed the file still gets written, it just doesn't delete the temp files and it's much more rare.

I was wondering if there was a way of improving the robustness of my program so that issues with Dropbox don't stop the files from writing.

This is the code I have for writing the images. As I said it works fine if the target directory is outside of Dropbox but it would be a shame if I couldn't get it to work within Dropbox as I was trying to take the tedium out of mass-manipulating the images I'm working with and boil it down to as few clicks as possible.

```
public boolean resizeImage( File original, OutputDimension dim ) {
    String filename = getOriginalFilename( original );
    String outFilename = dim.getOutputFilename(filename);
    try {
        BufferedImage resized = getResizedImage(original, dim );
        if( resized == null ) {
            return false;
        }
        File outFile = new File(outFilename);
        if( !outFile.exists() ) {
            outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            if( outFile.createNewFile() ) {
                System.out.println("Created file for writing.");
            }
        }
        outFile.setWritable(true);
        if( outFile.canWrite() ) {
            System.out.println("Trying to write " + outFile );
            return ( ImageIO.write(resized, dim.formatName, outFile ) );
        } else {
            System.err.println("Can't open " + outFilename + " for writing.");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't write to file " + outFilename );
        return false;
    }
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: [outFilename] (Access is denied)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(FileImageOutputStream.java:69)
at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(FileImageOutputStreamSpi.java:55)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(ImageIO.java:419)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1530)
at com.drentsoft.cardresizer.ResizeJob.resizeImage(ResizeJob.java:98)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: its because dropbox is picking up the empty temp files, so why not write to temp directory and move the file from tempdirectory into dropbox

Comment: Why are you calling `setWritable(true)`? Does it fail when you make the new directories? What about your `outfile.canWrite()` test, Does that ever fail? Why do you create the file for writing instead of just writing the file? Have you tried writing the file again immediately after failing?

Comment: @matt I added setWritable(true) because I found a suggestion somewhere online and as far as I've seen canWrite hasn't returned false.

Comment: I was trying to make as general purpose program as possible so while the project I'm working on at the moment is Dropbox based, future ones might not be but I guess it might be worth trying the temp folder approach anyway.

Comment: I would suggest to only modify the file once, eg. Don't create it, and set writable. Make sure the parent directory exists and then try to write it. Also, when you write it, give it one or two tries before permanently failing.

Comment: ok thanks I'll give that a go.

Comment: @matt OK I think I've got it, as you suggested I think it was too many checks/file creations. I simplified the code and added a loop to retry a few times on failure and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks both for the help.